# Can any one please correct it?

Tags: rest, soap

In either method REST/SOAP-RPC, HTTP is used to transport the message to the server from client.

In REST Method, HTTP should provide all the necessary details (in request) to be provided the response by server where as in SOAP-RPC, HTTP just sends the soap-envelop to the server.

From a client perspective, Client should know some logic to parse the soap message to display the end user for SOAP-RPC where as in REST, client does not care about and the same HTTP provide all the parsed information to the client.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP: In each request, soap sends HTTP POST Requests (HTTP GET doesnt exist). This Post request, contains an XML Message. For example, if you want to get a List of Items your HTTP Message is not a GET but a POST and contains a XML Message, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <soap:Body> 

          <p:getItemList xmlns:p="http://www.parts-depot.com"/> 

    </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

On the other hand with rest, your HTTP Request would be a GET Request and would look like this: http://www.example.com/getItemList

Comment: So as per your answer, HTTP is just hand over the soap message to the server. The same way the response will come in this fashion. Does client should know anything to parse the same soap message to display or not needed?

Comment: yes, the same way the the response will come. So the client need to parse, the message to get the data.

Comment: Hi Fabian, to parse the Soap message on client, do client should know any definitions or anything etc..?

Comment: The interfaces which a soap client is able to use, are defined in a wsdl file. Now, if you HTTP Post a XML Message with a request (e.g. getItems), you get back an answer (also an XML Message). You can treat this xml message as a string. This XML msg contains your data. But you could also parse the message to a java object. In java you could do it with JAXB for example. You may do first a JAXB tutorial. 
By the way, if you want to get a better understanding of soap, i recommend to use SoapUI (http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html).